# JQuery append div with children to an element is not working on firefox

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-hover

Why appending div with children to an element is not working on Firefox?

i wanna see this result:

```
<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
        <div class="d3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to create d1 with it's children and append to an element?

Comment: PLEASE GIVE MORE DETAIL ?

Comment: thanks for replay, i did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').append(
    $('<div class="d1"><div class="d2"><div class="d3"></div></div></div>')
)
```